# How to use middleware in Laravel for secure controllers?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I need to configure middleware in Laravel that all controllers will be secured by Auth.
I mean that will redirection for every incoming request if user is not authorized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the following in your routes file:

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'admin'], function () {
    Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth'], function() {
    ...Your routes here
```

This will apply the auth middleware to all routes prefixed with admin. You can of course also leave the prefix away if you don't need it.

Comment: `auth` is unable to discern from admin or user.

Comment: Indeed, but that was not the question I think.